# How to keep a submenu open when the page changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this JS code for my menu:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(e){
     if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
       $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
     }
  });
});
```

what is the best way to make the sub menus stay open when the page is changed - maybe using cookies or sessions?

I have created a jsfiddle here so you can see the full html and css etc: http://jsfiddle.net/bMkEj/

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using [HTML5 LocalStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

In the click handler, save the active menu text to localStorage:

```
$('#nav > li > a').click(function(e){
   ...
   localStorage.setItem("activeSubMenu", $(this).text());
});
```

On page load, read the localStorage and expand the menu (if found):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var activeItem = localStorage.getItem("activeSubMenu");
    if(activeItem){
        $('#nav > li > a').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == activeItem;
        }).slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: of course Internet Exploder <8 doesn't support this http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: If we only ever used technology that is supported by IE<8, then web would be a very dull and boring place.

Comment: oh believe me I care nothing about supporting IE 6 and 7. I just like to point it out to those who have to care

Comment: @MrCode I wonder how creating and executing a desktop JavaScript app would look like on Windows95...

Comment: @Ghillied it would probably look something like http://www.omnicognic.com/Support/34/Fatal_Error_Win98.png

Comment: @CharlieFord does it store anything to localstorage? Check by opening Chrome Dev Tools (F12), then Resources Tab > Local Storage > Select domain/site

Answer (score 1):

Pass a query parameter when you load the page and use it to select the appropriate nav item:

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="foo"><a href="index.html?nav=foo">Foo</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Foo 1</li>
            <li>Foo 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="bar"><a href="index.html?nav=bar">Bar</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Bar 1</li>
            <li>Bar 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="baz"><a href="index.html?nav=baz">Baz</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Baz 1</li>
            <li>Baz 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JS (assumes jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
    var matches = query.match(/nav=([^&]*)/);
    var id = matches[1];
    $('#' + id + ' ul').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP, or any other server-end language, you could add the active class to the active element.

EDIT: If you're just running JS you might be able to parse the url (window.location.href) and use that to set the active class.

Comment: okay - im not too great with JS. have you got an example i can see?

Comment: Depends on how your URLs look. Maybe `var str = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`, if your URLs are of the `/foo/bar` type, then `switch(str)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) on that to add the class to the desired element.

Comment: @CharlieFord here is a [**great example**](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/gZHn3/1/). Have fun :)